# XCode-like auto completion in vim (without tab)?

Tags: xcode, vim, autocomplete

Greetings. I've been using vim for years, and I've recently started toying with XCode. One of the things I really like about XCode is that it will **auto** complete words **without** me hitting `<TAB>`.

For instance, in this image below I only need to type `NSSObj` and the rest is filled in automatically, no special keystroke required.

[image]

I'd like to reproduce this effect in vim.

To be clear, this question is not about how to get tab/omni-completion working in vim. I've already got tab/omni completion working just fine and that's not a problem. The question is: does anyone know how to get vim to autocomplete *as I am typing* ?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with XCode.  If you don't hit tab, what do you do to accept their proposed completion (or reject, if what you really wanted was NSObjib)?

Comment: First of all, you don't really want to do this. Having omnicomplete constantly firing is a brain-rotter they put in modern IDEs because their users don't generally use keyboard commands/shortcuts. 

Second of all, if you persist with this terrible idea view the help on autocmd to see what event fires every time you enter in text in insert mode.

Comment: Whaledawg, thanks for pointing out autocmd. I've got autocomplpop.vim working and I can feel my brain slowly rotting away. It's a wonderful feeling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

vimscripts has a plugin called [autocomplpop.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) that does what you want.

Comment: Awesome. This plugin totally rocks. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is a vim script called [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) made by Shougo.

Comment: AutoComplPop is great but I found neocomplcache to be better.